# Как передать указатель на двойной массив в функцию

Tags: c++

Работаю с изображениями, которые конвертирую в набор пикселей двумерного массива; Есть функции которые производят действия над двумерными массивами, и так как изображения бывают разных размеров, невозможно передать функции двумерный массив, не того размера что в ней определен:

```
void func(int arg[2400][2400]);

int arr[1920][1080];

void func(arr);// ERROR
```

Максимум что работает это вид типа:

```
void func(int (*arr)[1080]);

int arr[1920][1080];

void func(arr);
```

Но и тут не все хорошо, потому что хотя бы одна сторона двумерного массива - все ровно должна  указываться конкретно, а это невозможно если изображения разного размера

```
void func(int (*arr)["размер"]);
```

Есть ли какие то механизмы передать в функцию, двойной массив не указывая его размеров вообще?

Comment: Пользоваться `C++`

Comment: В С++ нет двухмерых массивов. Массивы нельзя передавать (и возвращать) в функции по значению. Используйте `std::vector` или какой-нибудь спец класс для двух- / много- мерных матриц

Comment: @VTT, как нет, вы серьёзно чтоли, где написано, что он по значению хочет передать?

Comment: @PavelGridin Да, их серьезно нет.

Comment: @VTT Имеете в виду, что нет двухмерных массивов переменного размера? Или что на самом деле двухмерные массивы - это массивы массивов?

Comment: @VTT, попробуйте погуглить на тему многомерные массивы в C++

Comment: @HolyBlackCat То что массивы есть только одномерные. В фортране например есть полноценные многомерные массивы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, в каком контексте мог возникнуть такой вопрос. В С++ не существует двумерных массивов, у которых оба размера становятся известными только на стадии выполнения. А в реальной практике обычно требуется именно это. Поэтому многомерные массивы заранее неизвестного размера на практике либо реализуют на базе одномерных (с ручным пересчетом индексов), либо как "рваные массивы", т.е. массивы указателей на подмассивы. (Будем считать, что `std::vector` из `std::vector` тоже попадает в последнюю категорию.)

Остаются только нишевые случаи, когда у вас в программе действительно необходимо работать с двумерными массивами разного размера, и при этом эти двумерные массивы явно объявлены как таковые: с известными на стадии компиляции размерами (как в вашем примере).

В такой ситуации у вас есть возможность реализовывать ваши функции, как шаблонные, с размерами, вынесенными в список параметров шаблона

```
template <unsigned N, unsigned M>
void func(int (&arg)[N][M])
{
  ...
}
```

А если вас по какой-то причине не устраивает шаблонное решение, то тогда придется писать функцию в терминах `int **` "массива"

```
void func(int *const *arg, int n, int m)
{
  // Работаем с arg[i][j]
}
```

а для передачи в нее вашего исходного массива

```
int arr[1920][1080];
```

сначала создавать временный промежуточный массив указателей

```
int *rows[1920];
for (int i = 0; i < 1920; ++i)
  rows[i] = arr[i];

func(rows, 1920, 1080)
```

---

В С в вашем распоряжении были бы VLA, которые прекрасно и элегантно решили бы эту проблему

```
void func(unsigned n, unsigned m, int arr[n][m])
{
  ...
}
```

Но в С++ у вас такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 0):

Адрес элемента рассчитывается умножением номера строки на размер строки и поэтому один размер - число элементов в строке придётся указывать обязательно

Answer (score 0):

Если у нас есть двумерный массив `m`, то вырвжение `m[i][j]`  интерпретируется как `*(*(m + i) + j)`. Матрица, представленная как двумерный массив, передается как указатель(не копируется), поэтому для передачи обеих размеров(строк и столбцов), один из решений таков:

```
void func(int* array, const unsigned row, const unsigned column)
{
    for (unsigned i{}; i < row; ++i) 
        for (unsigned j{}; j < column; ++j) {
            unsigned ij = i * column + j;           
            //использование  array[ij] 
        }   
    //...       
}
```

и пример

```
int m[4][2];
func(m[0], 4, 2); // m[0] равносильно  &m[0][0]
```

Comment: кто то сидит мои ответы минусует. А указать на ошибку кто будет?  Не серьезно и на детсад тянет

Comment: Я тоже заметил минусы. Но не только вас. Например, все отвечающие в этой теме были минусованы. Видимо какой-то неадекват. Будем надеяться,  что система заметит и откатит.

Comment: @avp,  это не понимание того, что  таким образом отрицательно влияют на рейтинг сайта, не помогают автору ответа понять свою ошибку, мешают читательям  выбрать и получать полезную информацию...